# Firestore denies add operation in web worker with completely open security rules (web-app)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, web-worker

So, I have setup the following web worker to add data to a Firestore Collection.

The first part of the web worker code initializes Firebase and get some references

```js
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.1/firebase-app.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.1/firebase-auth.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.1/firebase-firestore.js");

// firebase configuration object
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "XXX",
  authDomain: "XXX",
  projectId: "XXX",
  storageBucket: "XXX",
  messagingSenderId: "XXX",
  appId: "XXX"
};
// initialize firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// get reference to db
const db = firebase.firestore();
// get reference to collection
const collection = db.collection("data");
```

The following function performs the actual upload inside the web worker (at least in my intentions)

```js
// function to handle document upload to firestore
const uploadData = async document => {
  // try to
  try {
    // sign in anonymously to firebase
    await firebase.auth().signInAnonymously();
    // upload document
    const docRef = await collection.add(document);
    // output docRef to console
    console.log(docRef);
    // signout
    firebase.auth().signout();
  }
  // on error
  catch(error) {
    // output error to console
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    console.log(error, errorCode, errorMessage);
  };
};
```

Finally, this is the event-listener to start the web worker:

```js
// event handler
onmessage = async function(e) {
  // cache data
  const workerData = e.data;
  // upload data to firestore
  await uploadData(workerData);
  // send upload finished
  postMessage("upload finished");
};
```

The Firestore rules are completely open (just for testing purposes):

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
     allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Still, when my web worker runs, I receive the following error in the console:

```
"permission-denied" "Missing or insufficient permissions"
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For some strange reason, in the current firebase project, the config object was missing the prop "databaseURL".
I deleted the project, created a new one and the code worked as expected. As a matter of fact, the new firebase config object had the "databaseURL" prop correctly set.